# Gettin values based on longitude on latitude from a SpatialPixelsDataFrame in R

Tags: r, raster

I have several locations in longitude and latitude coordinates and I need to get an estimate of solar radiation for each location.

I found data from NASA that has exactly this information in a 1 degree x 1 degree resolution.

```
nasafile <- 'http://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/sse/global/text/global_radiation'
nasa <- read.table(file=nasafile, skip=13, header=TRUE)

head(nasa)
  Lat  Lon  Jan  Feb  Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep  Oct  Nov   Dec  Ann
1 -90 -180 9.63 5.28 0.75   0   0   0   0   0 0.1 3.24 8.28 10.97 3.19
2 -90 -179 9.63 5.28 0.75   0   0   0   0   0 0.1 3.24 8.28 10.97 3.19
3 -90 -178 9.63 5.28 0.75   0   0   0   0   0 0.1 3.24 8.28 10.97 3.19
4 -90 -177 9.63 5.28 0.75   0   0   0   0   0 0.1 3.24 8.28 10.97 3.19
5 -90 -176 9.63 5.28 0.75   0   0   0   0   0 0.1 3.24 8.28 10.97 3.19
6 -90 -175 9.63 5.28 0.75   0   0   0   0   0 0.1 3.24 8.28 10.97 3.19
```

As you can see, it has monthly data as well as an mean annual average for a paticular lat/lon coordinate in by 1 degrees.

If I convert this to a `SpatialPixelsDataFrame` object:

```
proj <- CRS('+proj=latlon +ellps=WGS84')
coords <- nasa[,2:1]
data <- nasa[,3:15]
nasaSP <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points=coords, data=data, proj4string=proj)
```

I would like to know how to extract the annual value for a particular latitude and longitude coordinate.

I have no experience in geographic data analysis and I have been following this post: https://www.r-bloggers.com/maps-of-solar-radiation/ , but the point of it was to get a map and I just need to extract particular values and don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would convert the `SpatialPixelsDataFrame` to a raster object in order to use the functionality of the `raster` package. Particularly for extracting values, it's easier if it's a `raster` object since you can extract values at any given location.

In this case, I'll convert it to a brick, which is a raster with multiple layers (since we have multiple variables).

```
library(raster)

# convert to brick

rbck <- brick(nasaSP)

# output

> rbck
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 180, 360, 64800, 13  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : -180.5, 179.5, -90.5, 89.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       :   Jan,   Feb,   Mar,   Apr,   May,   Jun,   Jul,   Aug,   Sep,   Oct,   Nov,   Dec,   Ann 
min values  :  0.00,  0.00,  0.17,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.10,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  1.51 
max values  :  9.97,  8.20,  7.54,  7.79,  8.31,  9.05,  8.49,  7.89,  7.38,  8.28,  9.31, 11.19,  6.98
```

If you only want to look at one variable (you mentioned the annual value), you can easily subset it:

```
solAnn <- rbck[['Ann']]

# plot

plot(solAnn)
```

Now if you want to extract values, you can do it in multiple ways.

Suppose we have a matrix of coordinates:

`extcoords <- matrix(c(1:10,1:10),ncol=2)`

You can extract values either with the cell indices of the raster, which you can get with the function `cellfromXY`:

```
vals <- solAnn[cellFromXY(solAnn,extcoords)]
> vals
 [1] 5.49 5.43 5.28 5.06 4.53 4.81 5.12 5.37 5.52 5.79
```

Or you can convert the coordinates to spatial points and then use `extract` to get your values:

```
pj <- crs('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0')
pts <- SpatialPoints(coords = extcoords,proj4string = pj)

vals <- extract(solAnn,pts)

# Output 
> vals
 [1] 5.49 5.43 5.28 5.06 4.53 4.81 5.12 5.37 5.52 5.79
```

Using this method you can also add the points to your map with `points()`.

If you're interested in all values, you can also extract directly from the raster brick before you subset:

```
vals <- extract(rbck,pts)

# Output
> vals
       Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec  Ann
 [1,] 5.48 5.97 5.87 5.77 5.13 5.15 5.38 5.48 5.70 5.38 5.40 5.19 5.49
 [2,] 5.63 6.12 5.95 5.81 4.96 4.76 4.98 5.27 5.40 5.29 5.54 5.39 5.43
 [3,] 5.86 6.09 5.83 5.54 4.72 4.15 4.49 5.07 5.07 5.27 5.63 5.60 5.28
 [4,] 5.84 6.01 5.67 5.40 4.62 3.78 3.93 4.66 4.53 5.00 5.58 5.65 5.06
 [5,] 5.33 5.33 5.19 5.05 4.55 3.75 3.30 3.80 3.65 4.26 4.97 5.13 4.53
 [6,] 5.56 5.60 5.39 5.16 4.86 4.44 3.94 3.82 4.04 4.50 5.06 5.32 4.81
 [7,] 5.82 5.89 5.78 5.44 5.11 4.68 4.40 4.19 4.41 4.77 5.39 5.62 5.12
 [8,] 5.90 6.15 6.15 5.75 5.35 4.88 4.48 4.28 4.58 5.13 5.87 5.87 5.37
 [9,] 5.78 6.26 6.30 5.83 5.49 5.15 4.70 4.40 4.96 5.52 6.04 5.78 5.52
[10,] 5.69 6.15 6.40 6.24 6.08 5.70 5.35 5.08 5.46 5.84 5.85 5.59 5.79
```

HTH